# Why won't jQuery handle this JSON response properly?

Tags: jquery, django, json

I've been scratching my head over this for about an hour and a half now. So, I'm sending a form via $.ajax and expecting a json response back from django.

On the front end, js looks like this

```
        $.ajax({
            "type" : "POST",
            "url" : action,
            "dataType" : "json",
            "data" : serialized_form,
            "success" : function (data) {
                alert('hey')
                console.log(data);
                //$("#add_shipping").submit();
            },
            "error" : function (data) {
                alert(data)
            }
        });
```

On the back end, django is returning an HttpResponse object stuffed with the serialized json
like so ->

```
        redirectUrl = '/user/purchase/' + str(purchase.pk) + '/'
        response_data = {}
        response_data['redirect'] =  redirectUrl
        response_data['status'] = 200

        rsp = HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(response_data))
        rsp["CONTENT-TYPE"] = "application/json"

        return rsp
```

When jQuery gets the response, instead of logging it to the console like I have asked it to, it simply displays the formatted json in the browser surrounded by pre tags. I'm guessing this may have something to do with my Content-type header, but from what I can tell it's responding with 'application/json'. Can anyone think of what I may be doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably running that code in a form's submit event without cancelling the submit.

Therefore, the browser is submitting the form and navigating to that page.

Add `return false`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm working on it now, however I am returning false as far as I can tell. I'm digging deeper, but it seems like this is the right track.

Comment: Well guys, I was actually trying to submit one form within the callback of the other's submit function, turns out I was targeting the wrong form. However, due to SLaks being so close to the right answer, the tick goes his way. Thanks for the help folks : )